# SciPy: Symmetric permutation of sparse CSR matrix

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, octave, linear-algebra

I'd like to symmetrically permute a sparse matrix, permuting rows and columns in the same way. For example, I would like to rotate the rows and columns, which takes:

```
 1     2     3
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
```

to

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 2     3     1
```

In Octave or MATLAB, one can do this concisely with matrix indexing:

```
A = sparse([1 2 3; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]);
perm = [2 3 1];
Aperm = A(perm,perm);
```

I am interested in doing this in Python, with NumPy/SciPy. Here is an attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

row = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2])
col = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 1])
A = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))

p = np.array([1, 2, 0])

#Aperm = A[p,p]            # gives [1,1,1], the permuted diagonal
Aperm = A[:,p][p,:]        # works, but more verbose
```

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this sort of symmetric permutation of a matrix?

(I'm more interested in concise syntax than I am in performance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MATLAB

```
A(perm,perm)
```

is a block operation.  In `numpy` `A[perm,perm]` selects elements on the diagonal.

```
A[perm[:,None], perm]
```

is the block indexing.  The MATLAB diagonal requires something like `sub2ind`. What's concise in one is more verbose in the other, and v.v.

Actually `numpy` is using the same logic in both cases.  It 'broadcasts' one index against the other,  A `(n,)` against `(n,)` in the diagonal case, and `(n,1)` against `(1,n)` in the block case.  The results are `(n,)` and `(n,n)` shaped.

This `numpy` indexing works with sparse matrices as well, though it isn't as fast.    It actually uses matrix multiplication to do this sort of indexing - with an 'extractor' matrix based on the indices (maybe 2, `M*A*M.T`).

---

MATLAB's documentation about a permutation matrix:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html#f6-13070